# I cannot establish connection between two containers in Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, docker, heroku

I have a web application built using Node.js and MongoDB. I have containerized the app using Docker and it was working fine locally but once i have tried to deploy it to production I couldn't establish connection between the backend and MongoDB container. For some reason the environment variables are always undefined.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  food-delivery-db:
    image: mongo:4.4.10 
    restart: always
    container_name: food-delivery-db
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: food-delivery-db  
    volumes:
      - food-delivery-db:/data/db
    networks: 
      - food-delivery-network

  food-delivery-app:
    image: thisk8brd/food-delivery-app:prod
    build: 
      context: .
      target: prod
    container_name: food-delivery-app
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - food-delivery-db
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://food-delivery-db/food-delivery-db
    networks: 
      - food-delivery-network

volumes: 
  food-delivery-db:
    name: food-delivery-db

networks: 
  food-delivery-network:
    name: food-delivery-network
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is expected behaviour](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime):

> Docker images run in [dynos the same way that slugs do](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos), and under the same constraints:
>
> - …
> - Network linking of dynos is not supported.

Your MongoDB container is great for local development, but you can't use it in production on Heroku. Instead, you can select and provision [an addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) for your app and connect to it from your `web` container.

For example, [ObjectRocket for MongoDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ormongo#provisioning-the-add-on) sets an environment variable `ORMONGO_RS_URL`. Your application would connect to the database via that environment variable instead of `MONGODB_URI`.

If you'd prefer to host your database elsewhere, that's fine too. I believe [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas) is the official offering.

Comment: thank you that worked for, i did use MongoAtlas to host my db and it all working fine since i am new with Docker i thought that i could push my db countainer to production, that was dumb

Comment: It wasn't dumb, @FaicalElJabli. You just hadn't learned about this part of Heroku yet. We all make mistakes and learn as we go.